# BIOS entries erased from Lenovo laptop

Tags: bios, multi-boot

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 laptop which I've been using as an Ubuntu/Windows 8 dual boot for two years. When I turned it on yesterday it didn't boot straight into Windows like it was supposed to, it booted into an old Ubuntu entry that doesn't work. It rebooted itself and looped in the same way. 
**Is this hard drive/motherboard failure or just a random BIOS glitch?**

I went into the BIOS to reconfigure the entries when I saw that my actual Ubuntu and Windows entries were erased. However I could force it to boot from a USB drive which I had an Ubuntu installation on and tried to reinstall GRUB with boot-repair. When it asked me to choose the drive to install on I chose the internal drive but it failed to install. I went back and told it to install to a small external USB drive, and it installed fine. I rebooted and the same thing happened. I think that it means that the MBR is corrupted.
**Again, is this hard drive/motherboard failure or just a random glitch?**

I booted into the new GRUB to test it out and it let me boot into the Ubuntu that I had installed on my hard drive, but since I had installed GRUB in legacy mode Grub couldn't boot Windows. The BIOS cannot boot from external drives if it's on BIOS mode so I can't install GRUB like that.

I have a few questions:

1. Is it a software or hardware issue?
2. Do I need to change any hardware?
3. How can I reinstall the Windows boot loader? (It's our family PC and my kids need Windows to be able to do their homework)
4. Because of other things I've found online I think that the MBR is corrupted. How can I fix it, preferrably without having to format or change the drive?

**EDIT 1 - SMART scan**

[image: SMART scan results]

I don't know what the results mean but I do know that it failed. Does that mean that the hard drive is damaged?

Thank you

Comment: You probably have GPT partition table on your hard disk, which doesn't have MBR at all. Boot Ubuntu from USB drive and add your [SMART readings](http://askubuntu.com/q/528072/129094) to this question (you can [edit] it).

Comment: I am at work and won't have access to the PC until this afternoon (in around 8 hours)

Comment: ill post a new question with the output when I get it

Comment: Please don't do that, there's no point in posting new one. Editing will bump this one to the top.

Comment: Ok. I just want to get this fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: Here you go. I posted the results of the scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SMART results show that the hard disk has uncorrectable sectors. That explains behavior you've described and indicates that your HDD is dying. You should:

1. Stop using it to avoid further damage (it's more likely when drive is running than when it's not)
2. Buy a new one
3. Preferably clean-install Windows and copy your files from the old drive (cloning might work, but you'll have to deal with booting issues yourself, cloning won't fix it automagically)